# Is it possible to write C/C++ code in Libgdx?

Tags: java, c++, c, libgdx

How do you write native (C/C++) code with Libgdx that works for Android and desktop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to their github project](https://github.com/badlogic/libgdx) libgdx is a "Cross-platform Java game development framework based on OpenGL ES". I've just searched for "libgdx with c++" and ended up at their [main site](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) which says it's written in Java/C++/C — but that doesn't mean it's available as a C/C++ library, and I can't see anything to that effect on their site, so I'd assume the answer to your question is that you can't use it in the way you would like.

Comment: Do you think [this](http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App) will work here?

Comment: Seems like it'd be a big hack to me, and potentially unstable on newer Android releases. If you really want to use libgdx I think you'd be best just using Java.

Comment: @LaceySnr About the cross platforming of libgdx, i searched about it on google and found out that if one wants to build a game for Android, iOS and desktop - that is possible. He need to create a shared project and an interface - one in Android, one in iOS and one in C#, according to this the shared project must be native(c or c++) so I do believe one can program natively using libgdx.